SessionAware this.getSession().get("key") always giving null struts2
Using struts2, used SessionAware to keep userObject in session, I find out during the MainAction execution  userObject setting properly in session, but while getting  userObject in a differnt flow in another action(UploadAction) class every time its returning null. Checked lot of things but no use. I am new to struts and SessionAware, What I am missing here? Put all relevant code down here.
public class WelcomeAction extends MainAction {

private UserObject userObject = new UserObject();
public String executeAction() {

userObject = //DB CALL;
this.getSession().put("user", userObject);
System.out.println("++"+this.getSession().get("user"));
    //giving me UserObject

}
}

public class MainAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
static Map<String,Object> session;

public MainAction() {       
        
    }



public Map<String,Object> getSession() {
        return session;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String,Object> session) {
        BaseAction.session = session;
    }


}


public class UploadAction extends MainAction implements ServletRequestAware{

public String executeAction() {

 UserObject uobj = (UserObject) this.getSession().get("user");// this line always give me null;
 
 //this uobj always null

}

}
struts.xml

    <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="sessionInterceptor"
                class="***.SessionInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <default-interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
        
        
        <action *******.WelcomeAction
            method="executeAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">*******</result>
        </action>
        
        
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="logInterceptor" class="*********LogInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor name="sessionInterceptor" class="*********.SessionInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="logInterceptor" />       
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />             
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>     
        <default-interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
        
        
        <action name="upload"
            class="*******.UploadAction"
            method="executeAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="Upload">
            </interceptor-ref>                     
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="noCache">true</param>
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">false</param>
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
                <param name="includeProperties">sessionId.*,lstError.*,success.*,message.*</param>
            </result>   
            
            <result name="input" type="json">
                <param name="noCache">true</param>
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">false</param>
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
                <param name="includeProperties">success.*,message.*</param>
            
        </action> 

        
        web.xml 
        <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>*******</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>*******.Process******
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



SessionInterceptor::
    
    if ( !className.equalsIgnoreCase("WelcomeAction")
              && !className.equalsIgnoreCase("com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport")
              && ( session == null || session.isEmpty()) ) {
            return "session";
        } else {
            
            return actionInvocation.invoke();
        }

LogInterceptor

Map session = (Map)ActionContext.getContext().get("session");
        UserObject userObject = this.getSession().get("user"));
        if(userObject==null){
            
            return "session";
        }
        else{
            
        }
      
        String result = invocation.invoke();
    


There's nothing to do with Struts, if the session object is null then either it is not available in the db or your session ocussiantly invalidated. Clarify your problem and add details.  As far as it's written the answer is impossible.

Hi @Roman , userObject is not null from db. That I checked with debug . Where can I check if session getting invalidated, I added all code , do you need struts.xml and Inceptor class code as well.

Yes, you can add struts.xml, web.xml

Hi @RomanC I have added struts.xml web.xml and inceptor  code as as much as possible. Could you please check once. Thanks in Advanced.

You have used different properties to inject a session object to the action. One is a property of MainAction and another is in BaseAction. When you call this.getSession() then it returns a session from the MainAction but when a session object is injected the property is of BaseAction.
You should change a setter method to assign a session object to the MainAction when it was injected
@Override
    public void setSession(Map<String,Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

don't use static properties of the action.

Also to implement correctly SessionAware you can read this answer:

To get a SessionMap there's another approach. Let your action class to implement SessionAware and make sure you have configured a default interceptor stack for the action. After that the session map should be injected to the action instance. More about it here.


Also you have created two interceptor-stack with a name loggingStack one of each override the other.

Though there was a typo to call in         BaseAction.session = session; this line, in my main code I have used MainAction.session. The last line resolved my issues. "Also you have created two interceptor-stack with a name loggingStack one of each override the other." Thanks a lot @Roman C
